# revoked ssl certificate vs. page loading

Tags: javascript, ssl, https

So I'm dealing with a revoked ssl certificate issue.  I have a page that includes a script that points to an https location.  The page itself is for example:

`https://www.mysite.com/somePage.html`

On the page I have the following:

`<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.othersite.com/script.js'></script>`

So the ssl cert for `www.othersite.com` was revoked. I've done research on how to deal with that, and that's not really the question I have.

My question has to do with accessing the `https://www.mysite.com/somePage.html` itself, with a script on the page pointing to a revoked ssl certificate.

Now, I know that if the page itself was attempting to use a revoked certificate, the browser (assuming it performed a check) would not allow me to even go to the page. But if it was just an expired ssl cert then it would give me the option to ignore it and proceed anyway.

So what about if the page itself has a valid ssl cert but the script on the page is using a revoked ssl cert?  Will the browser simply load the page but not the script? Will it give me some kind of "mixed content" type warning?  Or will it not allow me to view the page at all, same as if the actual page were using a revoked ssl cert?

Basically I'm concerned that because the script on the page currently has a revoked ssl cert, that some people might not even be able to view the page at all..

Comment: it's better to try than ask for something like that...

Comment: well, i have tried, and i'm getting mixed results. I'm not sure if it's because of current browser settings or what. And I can't feasibly test this for every browser/version/setting out there, so I was hoping someone would have a definitive answer or spec to link to that explains what's *supposed* to happen in this scenario

Comment: it shouldn't stop the main page. whether the external script loads or not is browser-dependent. whether a message is displayed or not depends on the browser. can you just copy the script to your domain?

Comment: okay that's what i am seeing so far. So far it seems to be a mixed bag as far as whether or not browser will give me a message or not. But so far it hasn't stopped the actual page from loading (vs. browser not offering me an option if the page itself was using a revoked cert).  But as I said, I can't feasibly test all browsers/versions/settings so I was hoping to get a definitive answer as far as whether any browser would prevent the page from loading without even offering a "proceed" message :/

Comment: @dandavis actually fixing the problem isn't my issue. We have clear steps for that. Basically I'm trying to do damage assessment right now. Trying to figure out if anybody was unable to view the page. I figure at least some % dropped off because they didn't want to accept mixed content, but I'm trying to figure out if it's possible that a browser might not have even given them the option to proceed

Comment: while html5 and js spec error handling, there is no spec for browser-based error and human interaction relating to those. you can review your logs for images coded before and after the <script>, and see if the afters have fewer hits, but that probably wont work on modern browsers that "peek ahead" during load, like chrome and ff.